# Grafana variable using loki query

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

Is it possible in grafana to create a variable that uses a loki query where there isn't a label, that query needs to parse log lines that contain json to create adhoc labels.

I seem to be able to build a query in the loki explorer to do this but there doesn't appear to be the ability to run adhoc queries in grafana against a loki data source.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with creating labels on the fly (in your case probably using `| json`)?

Comment: I can't see where on the grafana ui I can add `| json`, the only options appear to be for label names or label values when I select loki as the source

Comment: Hmm, interesting. In fact you can only put a stream selector. As I understand fully-fledged queries are not allowed.